# getting send: spawn id exp6 not open error

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I know that this issue has many solutions mentioned here, but I am middle of this issue.
I have created a ruby script **snaps.rb**.

This script for deleting the lvm snapshots. following code causing the problem

```
`/usr/bin/expect <<delim
exp_internal 0
set timeout 20
spawn echo itsme | sudo -S lvremove #{snap_name}
expect {Do you really want to remove active logical volume #{name}? [y/n]:}
send "y\r"
expect eof 
delim`
```

*snap_name* is my *snapshot name* and I am using expect for passing y or n to the command input. and I am using **backtick(``)** for executing the shell command from ruby. 
but I getting following error.

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
""end "n
```

How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate out `echo itsme | sudo -S lvremove #{snap_name}`

try this

```
`/usr/bin/expect <<delim
exp_internal 0
set timeout 20
spawn sudo lvremove #{snap_name}
send "itsme\r"
expect {Do you really want to remove active logical volume #{name}? [y/n]:}
send "y\r"
expect eof 
delim`
```